# Saxon/C EE 11.2's transform.c in C++

Tags: c++, saxon

I am writing C++ code. I plan to call the main function from "transform.c" , but the problem is that "transform.c" is written in c , converting in C++ would introduce a ton of errors. So is there any "transform.cpp" that I can use , I'm having a lot of trouble with the C API , so I thought I could just do this .

Comment: lets try with `extern C` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c-in-c

Answer (score 0):

use extern "C"

```
extern "C"{
  // c code
  // include copy code from transform.c and put here
  // or create new transform.cpp and #include "transform.c"
}
```